# Incorrectly returning the value of a Node at position 'm' in a linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, nodes

I have a homework problem:

Find the element in a singly linked list that's m elements from the end.
For example, if a linked list has 5 elements, the 3rd element from the end is the 3rd element. The function definition should look like question5(ll, m), where ll is the first node of a linked list and m is the "mth number from the end". You should copy/paste the Node class below to use as a representation of a node in the linked list. Return the value of the node at that position.

The code to paste is the 4-line definition of **class Node**.  My attempt follows.

```
class Node(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

ll = None

# Provided Node Class.
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

# Function for adding values to list.
def add(new_data):
    global ll
    node = Node(new_data)
    node.next = ll
    ll = node

def Question5(ll, m):
    # Start of list.
    element = ll
    # Node count.
    c = 0
    # Set end of list to False.
    endlist = False
    # Loop until the linked list reaches its end.
    while not endlist:
        c += 1
        element = element.next
        if element.next == None:
            endlist = True

    # Set node value as count - position m
    position = c - m
    # If position is less than 0, end has been reached
    if(m < 0):
        return "8, End of list"
    # If not the end of list return value at position m
    else:
        return position

global ll
add(1)
add(2)
add(3)
add(4)
add(5)
add(6)
add(7)
add(8)
print ("Value of node at position m from the end is: ", Question5(ll, -1))
#('Value of node at position m from the end is: ', '8, End of list')
print ("Value of node at position m from the end is: ", Question5(ll, 3))
#('Value of node at position m from the end is: ', 4)
print ("Value of node at position m from the end is: ", Question5(ll, 2))
#('Value of node at position m from the end is: ', 5)
print ("Value of node at position m from the end is: ", Question5(ll, 0))
#('Value of node at position m from the end is: ', 7)
```

My reviewer says that my solution is incorrect, as I am not returning the actual value of the node at position 'm'. What would be the correct way to return the value of a node object in this scenario?

---

Edit: for the sake of finalizing this question I have included the solution I was able to implement as per the advice in the second answer below

New code:

```
ll = None

# Provided Node Class.
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

# Function for adding values to list.
def add(new_data):
    global ll
    node = Node(new_data)
    node.next = ll
    ll = node

def Question5(ll, m):
    # Nodes already traversed
    element1 = ll
    # Nodes from beginning
    element2 = ll
    # Node count.
    c = 0

    # Traverse list until c = m
    if(ll is not None):
        while(c < m):
            element2 = element2.next
            c += 1

    # Loop until the linked list reaches its end.
    while(element2 is not None):
        #print ("This is element 1:", element1.data)
        #print ("This is element 2:", element2.data)
        element1 = element1.next
        element2 = element2.next

    # return the current node at m steps from the end
    return element1.data

global ll
# List meant to represent a telephone with 0 being the end.
add("0")
add("9 WXYZ")
add("8 TUV")
add("7 PQRS")
add("6 MNO")
add("5 JKL")
add("4 GHI")
add("3 DEF")
add("2 ABC")
add("1")
# Singly Linked List:
# 1 - 2 ABC - 3 DEF - 4 GHI - 5 JKL - 6 MNO - 7 PQRS - 8 TUV - 9 WXYZ - 0
print ("node at position m in relation to the end of ll is: ", Question5(ll, 4))
# ('node at position m in relation to the end of ll is: ', '7 PQRS')
print ("node at position m in relation to the end of ll is: ", Question5(ll, 8))
# ('node at position m in relation to the end of ll is: ', '3 DEF')
print ("node at position m in relation to the end of ll is: ", Question5(ll, 1))
# ('node at position m in relation to the end of ll is: ', '0')
print """---End Question 5---
```

Comment: Please note that your code is still wrong.  For instance, in the first test case, when you're supposed to return the 4th node from the end -- that would be **4 GHI** -- you instead return the 4th node from the front, **7 PQRS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your output: when **m** is 2, your code returns 5.  The problem statement clearly shows that it expects 7, the second element counting form the end of the list.  Your code backs off two extra elements: apparently, the only way you allow returning 8 is to give a position of -1, and 0 is required to get a value of 7.

Fix your counting, and you'll be fine; you're already handling the traversal correctly.

---

Now that I've had time to look over the code, I'm going to back off from my previous answer somewhat: you do get to the end of the list properly, but that's about all your code does correctly.  To look at this from a functional standpoint, your reviewer is entirely correct: you don't return the node's value at all.  You compute a position and *assume* that the node's value matches.  You're not allowed to do that.

Consider a list built this way, on phone buttons:

```
add("ABC")
add("DEF")
add("GHI")
add("JKL")
add("MNO")
add("PRS")
add("TUV")
add("WXY")
add("QZ")
```

If the input is 2, you have to return "WXY".  I just tried this with your **Question5** code, and it still returns numbers.  Wrong.

You have to find your way to the end of the list, and then find the proper *value* from the end of the list.  There are various ways to do this.  For instance, build a list of node values as you traverse the list; then just print the value from position **-m** in that list.  Another possibility is to use recursion to find the end of the list, then return a counter back up the recursion chain to figure out which instance should print the value of the current node.

Can you take the next steps on your own.

Comment: So this would mean that I should use `c = 1` initially instead of `c = 0` ? The way I was marked off for this led me to believe that I had done the traversal incorrectly as that was what my reviewer told me I needed to do. You're telling me that I've done the traversal correctly.. Should I take this up with my reviewer?

Comment: Yes I think I'll be able to move forward from here, thank you for your in depth feedback.